# Subnetting a Class C network

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

An ISP has provided your company with the Class C network 192.111.2.0. Divide this into four (4) subnets.

Complete the following table; both Network addresses and Broadcast addresses should be in dotted-decimal notation.

Assume the all zero's and all one's subnets are usable.

Comment: Classfull networking was obsoleted in 1993. Whoever continues to teach it should be flogged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of material on subnetting - just google it and you'll get the result pretty easily. You can start with [this](http://www.subnet-calculator.com) subnet calculator.

As for your question:

In order to get 4 subnets from 192.111.2.0/24 you should go for the following configuration:

The subnet mask for all subnets are 255.255.255.192 (or /26) and the networks are divided as follows:

1. 192.111.2.0-192.111.2.63
2. 192.111.2.64-192.111.2.127
3. 192.111.2.128-192.111.2.191
4. 192.111.2.192-192.111.2.255

Notice that the first address is the network address and the last is the broadcast address